# scaling user controlls to the width of flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have a flowlayoutpanel with anchors to all 4 sides so it scales with the form size. i'm adding some user controls to it dynamicly. i want the user controls to scale with the flowlayoupanel verticaly. i tried this approach:

```
public void OnSizeChange(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (UserControl cont in controls)
            {
                cont.Width = flowLayoutPanel1.ClientSize.Width - 10;
            }
        }
```

and adding this function to form SizeChanged event but this is too laggy when resizing the window. is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: SuspendLayout() before the loop, ResumeLayout() after it.  Tends not the solve the problem when the user controls have a lot of child controls or the FlowLayoutPanel is being misused as a grid control.  Then use the form's ResizeBegin() event to temporarily hide the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395754/flowlayoutpanel-automatic-width-for-controls) might help you, it seems to describe the same problem you're having

Basically the solution seems to be a glorified version of the code you posted, I don't know if the performance improvement is significant.